# What multicastgroup should we refer if two Ignite clusters are managing in single subnet?

Tags: ignite

We had a peculiar situation where we created two Ignite clusters (20 nodes and 20 nodes) in the same network (same subnet).

The issue what we are having is that data is colliding between both ignite cluster and unable to differentiate.  We have found that we need to configure multicastgroup to diversify data set at each cluster level.   But the question is, what IP we need to refer in the  multicastgroup and what exactly that IP is referring to? is that referring to subnet IP?

ex: default-config.xml

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
    <property name="multicastGroup" value="228.1.2.4"/> 
   <property name="addresses">
      <list>
         <value>IP:port..port</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ONLY multicast, then you can omit the `addresses` property overall. `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` allows to use both multicast and statically provided IPs. The `addresses` property is for the latter.

Comment: Thanks Valentin!   but in my situation where  i have two clusters in the same network,  what should i put in multicast ?  because my ignite requests are getting mixed results if i define only static IP's since two clusters are in the same network.

Comment: In this case just provide different multicast group IPs for different cluster. Or you can use static configuration like described here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-isolated-ignite-clusters-on-same-set-of-machines

Comment: Valentine!  We were able to succeed by eliminating multicast completely and only defining static IP's.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to succeed by eliminating multicastgroup completely and only defining static IPs for each cluster seperately.  Thanks for the help.